# Looking for code to remove matching values from a large list of columns imported into excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for code to replace the bottom of the code I have posted below that will help remove all duplicate values found (including the value used to determine if there are duplicates) between 2 columns, and then proceed throughout the remaining columns to continue the duplicate search.

I have 2 tabs, a tab with a button to run a userform which collects a month and year field, and a tab that has the data dumped from the corresponding 2 files to the month and year selected.

The HOPE data is dumped into columns A, D, G, J, etc in steps of 3 up to 31 times (one set of data for each date in a month).
The SP data is dumped into columns B, E, H, K, etc in steps of 3 up to 31 times (one set of data for each date in a month).
This means that columns A and B will have HOPE and SP data, and column C will be empty, D and E will have HOPE and SP data, and F will be empty.

The code I have for moving the data is long and not complicated, doesn't take too much time, so I am not so much worried about that.

The time consuming task is comparing the HOPE and SP column for each date to remove matching pairs from both columns.

The variable `e` below is in place because there are 2 comboboxes and that has the potential to produce 2 errors. Instead of ending the sub immediately upon the first error, it will check for all errors and then end the sub.

This sub is comparing up to 6-digit numerical values with no text.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim month As String, year As String, lrA As Long, lrB As Long, a As Integer, b As Integer, e As Integer, i As Integer, x As Integer

e = 0
If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    ComboBox1.BackColor = vbRed
    ComboBox1.SetFocus
    e = 1
End If
If ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
    ComboBox2.BackColor = vbRed
    ComboBox2.SetFocus
    e = 1
End If

If e = 1 Then
    GoTo ES
End If

month = ComboBox1.Value
year = ComboBox2.Value

Unload UserForm1

Workbooks.Open ("\\filelocation\HOPE - " & month & " " & year & ".xlsx")
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Dump")
    x = 1
' 1
    i = 3
    .Range("A1") = "HOPE"
    Do
        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Columns(x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
' 2
    x = x + 3
    .Range("D1") = "HOPE"
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Columns(x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
' 3
    x = x + 3
    .Range("G1") = "HOPE"
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
    Do
        .Range("G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Columns(x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
' This continues up to 31 using the same steps as above.
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Workbooks.Open ("\\filelocation\SP - " & month & " " & year & ".xlsx")
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Dump")
' 1
    x = 2
    i = 3
    .Range("B1") = "SP - 01"
    Do
        .Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' 2
    x = x + 3
    i = 3
    .Range("E1") = "SP - 02"
    Do
        .Range("E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' 3
    x = x + 3
    i = 3
    .Range("H1") = "SP - 03"
    Do
        .Range("H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' This continues up to 31 using the same steps as above.
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Close False

If month = "February" Or month = "April" Or month = "June" Or month = "September" Or month = "November" Then
    Worksheets("Data Dump").Range("CM:CN") = ""
End If

With Worksheets("Data Dump")
    x = 1
    Do
        lrA = .Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
        lrB = .Cells(Rows.Count, x + 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For b = lrB To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(b, x + 1).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(b, x + 1).Delete
                GoTo nextB
            Else

            End If

            For a = lrA To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(b, x + 1).Value <> .Cells(a, x).Value Then

                Else
                    .Cells(a, x).Delete
                    .Cells(b, x + 1).Delete
                    GoTo nextB
                End If
            Next a
nextB:
        Next b
        x = x + 3
    Loop While x < 93
End With

ES:
End Sub
```

At the bottom of the sub is the comparison between columns to determine if duplicate values exist. It removes all matching numbers from both columns (A and B to start) before moving on to compare other columns (D and E, G and H, etc). Is there a better way to do this comparison? `.RemoveDuplicates` does not work because it leaves one of the duplicate values and removes the rest, whereas I want to remove any matching numbers between columns. Duplicate values *in* columns is already taken care of when the data is moved over, so there is no chance that a pair already removed would have one value left over that should have been removed but cannot be because it does not match after the first rotation through.

There has also been some trouble with this code that inserts (or prevents) some of the cells moving up so that there are blank cells between numbers. I am unsure where this originates, but will continue to test.

It appears that before the code that compares the columns, everything imports correctly. After the comparison is done, there are blank gaps between some HOPE-column related columns and several numbers are erroneously moved to the blank columns.

It also seems that activating the worksheet that has the data dumped into it before doing the comparison slows it down. Not switching over to the sheet with `.Activate` allows it to complete a fair margin faster. I have removed `.Activate` from the code above; it was previously directly under the declaration of the worksheet "Data Dump" for the comparison code.

I have confirmed that all import is done correctly and gets rid of duplicates. However, row 94 has had values to the left of column E shifted one to the right from the SP column. (So, F94, I94, etc) have a value in them for an inexplicable reason. There are also still gaps between some numbers past column E, most notably in the HOPE column. I am thinking it is possible that some part of this code moves SP column numbers into the HOPE column. Will need to test further after the holiday.

Comment: Code that works but needs optimization should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  If there is a specific problem with the code please indicate the line that is throwing the error.  Otherwise it is too broad for this forum.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm not looking for code optimization; I want to know if there is a different, better way to do what the code I posted is doing. For example, I am using double For brackets inside a Do loop whereas it could be done with a single bracket of _something_ that does a better job. In other words, I want to know if there is a different way to do it, not how to change my code to do it's job more efficiently. I have also listed several problems encountered at the bottom of the post. For that, I'm still going to be testing to see where the errors start occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved whatever problems were occurring by simplifying the code and making it shift cells up when a cell was deleted. There are no more blank cells or cells moved to a column they are not supposed to be in. It still isn't quick, but this does the job perfectly while the previous code still has excessive errors.

```
With Worksheets("Data Dump")
    x = 1
    Do
        lrA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
        lrB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, x + 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For b = lrB To 2 Step -1
            For a = lrA To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(a, x).Value = .Cells(b, x + 1).Value Then
                    .Cells(a, x).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                    .Cells(b, x + 1).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next a
        Next b
        x = x + 3
    Loop While x < 92 ' 91 is the last (31st) day that needs to be calculated.
    .Activate
End With
```

This does look like it is the best way to get rid of all matching values between 2 columns without removing entire rows where matching data is found. Other methods could be using `.Find` or `.Match` in various other ways to find the matching data and remove it and the base data, but this looks like it does the job the most efficiently and to-the-point.

Next stop, trying to see if there's a way to speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious improvements you can make. The most important one: don't do something like `.Cells(.Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row + 1` inside your `Do` loop. That way it will have to be calculated every time. Instead use a variable to hold that value (whatever it is you're trying to calculate) and use the variable inside the loop.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Though I am less worried about the import code because it is functional, and more worried about the duplicate check portion as it currently isn't doing what I think it should be doing. But thank you, I will take a look at that.